How to use C++ user defined modules in Arduino
Does Arduino support C++ module import functionality i.e. what would it require to implement something like this in Arduino: import std;?

Modules are a C++20 feature. The configuration files (platform.txt) of
the cores provided by Arduino all ask the compiler to use one of the
standards gnu++11, gnu++14 or gnu++17. These are C++11, C++14 and C++17
with some GNU extensions.
You will not be able to use C++ modules with standard Arduino cores. You
will use the traditional header files instead. Optionally, you may build
“Arduino libraries” by following the corresponding specification.

@Edgar Bonet Understood. Thank you for your comment. AOB: It appears someone gave my question a down vote. Could this have anything to do with my question itself or with the way it was framed? Feedback could help improve my future posts.

BTW, as per libraries, what's your thoughts on using third party vector container libraries? I saw one of such libraries which the author claimed could function like (but slightly different from) native std::vector<T> library. However, from your personal experience, could this pose potential drawbacks? Thank you in advance.

@beebee: I have no experience with those. I tend to use statically allocated plain C arrays, in order to avoid memory issues with dynamically-allocated memory.

Thank you so much. I appreciate your response
